# How to log in into Windows Ubuntu One Client as an restricted Windows User (Windows 7)?

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows, login, users, client

I have generated an account as Windows admin, but now I want to use the client as a restricted user. When I try to login there, it appears only the message "Getting information, please wait..." but nothing more. I did wait for about 10 minutes.
The client ist correctly setup in the windows firewall.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly have you got the latest version of the Ubuntu One Windows client? (2.01)
Secondly I'm not clear what you mean by "I have generated an account as Windows admin, but now I want to use the client as a restricted user".
Does that mean you created an Admin account and then changed it to a Standard account (that's the Windows term - not "restricted") or did you create an Admin account and then create another Standard Account?